# Why am I not getting text into /var/log/messages?

Tags: rhel-5, syslog

Today, I went to look at a backup RHEL5 server that doesn't usually need to get looked at very often. I found that `/var/log/messages` existed, but had a size of zero. Similarly, `messages.1`, `messages.2`, `messages.3`, and `messages.4` are also all empty.

- `/var/log/messages` has its correct permissions. (755)
- Reboot - No help.
- `rm -f /var/log/messages*` and `service syslog restart` - No help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to look at `/etc/syslog.conf`. It included the line

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local*.none;    /var/log/messages
```

This might be the problem. This is a backup DNS server, and I set up several `local*` syslog facilities once to do extra DNS logging. The `syslog` service might not actually like the `local*` partial wild card. So, change the line to

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local3.none;local4.none;local5.none;local7.none    /var/log/messages
```

and restart syslog.

Following the restart, /var/log/messages started populating again, and I could get on with solving the mystery that brought me back to this host to begin with...

So, solution: No partial string wildcards in /etc/syslog.conf. The facility is either `*` or a full string, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue under CentOS 6 - /var/log/messages.log was empty, `yum install syslog` showed "already installed" but when I tried `service syslog restart` or `service syslogd restart` it said "unrecognized service". Then I found in `/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog` and I tried `service rsyslog start` and bingo! it worked. Now `messages.log` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do much. Run below command on RHEL, that's enough.

journalctl -fn0 &

To exit, just type ctrl+d

cat /var/log/messages

wc -l /var/log/messages

Enjoy